# How can I change what days Carbon considers the weekend?

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I want to change `weekendDays` to only include **Sunday** in my Carbon Instance. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run:

```
Carbon::setWeekendDays([Carbon::SUNDAY]);
```

In your App\Providers\AppServiceProvider in the boot function.

Edit:

`setWeekendDays` is deprecated. Use macro instead.

```
Carbon::macro('isDayOff', function ($date) {
   return $date->isSunday();
});

$isDayOff = $carbon_inst->isDayOff(): bool;
```

Comment: `setWeekendDays` is deprecated. Use Macro instead.